# Why std::bad_alloc may end up not being caught?

Tags: c++, ios, macos, new-operator, bad-alloc

So I'm currently looking into `std::bad_alloc` and its behavior, and there's something I don't understand.

This very simple snippet:

```
try { 
    char* p = new char[10000000000ul];
} catch(std::bad_alloc& e) {
    std::cout << "Caught a bad alloc" << std::endl;
}
```

works and doesn't throw on my MacBook with 8GB of RAM. If I understand correctly, after reading a bit [about it](http://christiangarbin.blogspot.fr/2013/05/the-futility-of-catching-stdbadalloc.html)), it shows OSX may totally accept to allocate this amount of memory as virtual memory, though it means a lot of paging problem, switching pages between RAM and HDD.

Now if I execute this on my iPad with 1GB of RAM in a simple iOS application, I get:

> malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=10000007168) failed (error code=3)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc

I assume iOS is not happy with that amount of memory and just refuse to allocate it. Then, I understand `std::bad_alloc` is a serious error, but what exactly can cause it not to be caught here?

I reckon answer may be iOS/OSX specific and that the behavior may vary on other OSes/devices.

Comment: Is there any difference if you say `catch(const std::bad_alloc& e)`?

Comment: I didn't, will do tomorrow to check;

Comment: @JWWalker Nope, no difference.

Comment: I don't know why you can't catch `std::bad_alloc`. You are allocating > 9GB here. Something to keep in mind, is that desktops can and do paging automatically, but iOS does not. So you will never be able to allocate more than the physical RAM on iOS